# Study in Germany with Polish D type visa?

Tags: germany, study, poland

If I have a multi-entry type D visa from Poland, may I stay longer than 3 months in another Schengen state such as Germany for study purposes? Or, if I have to apply for a long term German national visa, can they extend my Polish visa?

Generally, what should I do if I want to study in Germany and I have an D type Polish visa valid for a year's period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Studying in Germany on a Polish D visa will not be practical. You are only allowed to stay in Germany for 90 days out of 180, which will not be enough to attend the lectures and exams of a term (even if you commute back to Poland every weekend).
- Germany cannot extend a Polish D visa, either.
- Germany can issue a German D visa, which is what you need. Being a legal resident of Poland *may* help you with the German application, depending on the particulars of your case. But you should ask on Expatriates SE for this.

Comment: Now that the question has been migrated, do you have anything else to add?

Comment: @phoog, I'd defer to the experts here.